# Update the way to limit a boundedvec

Tags: boundedvec, constants

I've developing a pallet where I'm using the following custom data type to save a CID: `types.rs`

```rust
pub type CID = BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<100>>;
```

I want to change the way I limit that boundedvec using a pallet constant as follows: `lib.rs`

```rust
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        #[pallet::constant]
        type MaximunCID: Get<u32>;
}
```

So, the final boundevec should be: `types.rs`

```rust
pub type CID = BoundedVec<u8,  <T as Config>::MaximunCID>;
```

Then set the value of the constant in the runtime `lib.rs`:

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub const MaximunCID:u32 = 100;
}
```

```rust
impl pallet_custom_pallet::Config for Runtime {
    type MaximunCID = MaximunCID;
}
```

#### Questions:

- Is a storage migration required to achieve it? As far as I understand, there's no change on the limit of the mentioned boundedvec. I just want to use a pallet constant to expose the limit in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a migration for this. In low-level, it's just a `Vec`.

---

Tips:
But if your `MaximunCID` is less than 100 and you have a "full" `BoundedVec`, that might be an issue. So, please check the existing storage first.

BTW, you can use `WeakBoundedVec` instead of performing a migration. (if it's full)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is fine. Just note that any reduction of that constant would incur a migration.
This may or may not be obvious to runtime developers that use your pallet, and should be documented.